# Batch Change Created Date using Automator and CSV File

Tags: applescript, automator, shortcuts-app

I have 1,500-some Facebook photos all showing with the same date as they come from a data download.

Through the magic of regular expressions, I have generated a CSV file where each row has the filename on the left and the correct timestamp on the right, example being:

`13170030_982552864458_69609533_o_982552864458.jpg{tab}7/29/2017 4:47:23 PM`

How would I go about batch changing the taken/modified/created dates for these files in Automator or Shortcuts?

I also have a Windows PC so if this isn't possible with MacOS but you know of a solution using Powershell or a COTS Windows product off-of-the-top-of-your-head, that's fine with me.

Comment: Does your regex magic allow to create timestamps in 24 hour format? It would simplify the batch renaming.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that you look into Phil Harvey's `exiftool`, platform agnostic and  written in Perl.

Comment: @fd0, please feel free to add this as an answer so that I can mark it as the solution. I did use exiftool with success. Thanks!